# Managing daily created tables for show data in datatables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, optimization, datatables

I have a system that saves millions of records daily to a table 'transactions' and we are now facing a huge problem with showing this data to the user. finally, I decided to create daily tables like '`transactions_20190915`', '`transactions_2019016`' and store data to those daily tables. now the issue is I'm using JQuery `DataTables` server-side processing and when I'm trying to get data from a date range I have to loop trough days. because of that, I'm having issues with `DataTables` sorting searching, etc.

I need to know whether there is a more efficient way to achieve my goal or how do I do this in a better way?

**Note: I'm using Laravel framework**

Comment: See about partitioning.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE; B) sample of your query and TEXT results of C) EXPLAIN SELECT .....   so we can see what the optimizer is doing with your query request.

Comment: Mistake number 1:  Having daily tables instead of a single table.

Comment: @WilsonHauck i just need a better theory or a method to overcome this issue.

Comment: @RickJames don't we goner get table corruptions and taking lot of time to run a query issues if we use a single table? then how do we overcome that?

Comment: @Strawberry i read the documentation and it says we do need to alter table every time that we are adding a partition. there is a probability that table can be corrupted when doing that and do i need to add a partition every day?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE .. REORGANIZE PARTITION ...;` -- If you are starting with an empty partition (`p_future`) that is empty, is very fast.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint